# Chartjs gradient background color based on min and max values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I'm using chartjs with vue-chart to display some data in my application and actually what I would like to achieve is to have a Bar chart with a background color from red to green.

The chart has dynamic min and max values but it cannot be less than 0 and greater than 5. Similar to a 5 star rating.

In order to show differences in the displayed data I'm not fixing the chart min/max from 0 to 5.

Currently this is the code to show my chart:

Options:

- min is -0.2 than minimum value but not less than 0;
- max is +0.2 than maximum value but not greater than 5;

  ```
  return {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            min,
            max,
            stepSize: 0.5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ```

Bar chart data:

```
  return {
    labels: this.labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Evaluation',
        data: [
          this.photo.composition,
          this.photo.technique,
          this.photo.creativity,
          this.photo.content,
          this.photo.lighting
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

Render chart:

```
  const gradient = this.$refs.canvas
    .getContext('2d')
    .createLinearGradient(0, 300, 0, 0)
  gradient.addColorStop(0, '#FF5722')
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, '#FFC107')
  gradient.addColorStop(1, '#8BC34A')

  this.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = gradient
  this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
```

The result is pretty close to what I'm looking for:

[image]

Unfortunately what I would like to see is the red color on 0 and green on 5 so the gradient should not reach the green if maximum value is 2.5 (here I would expect the orange) and the same for lower values... I hope it make sense.
Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterLayout` hook for creating a gradient for the y-axis that spreads that desired area (values 0 to 5).

```
let yAxis = chart.scales["y-axis-0"];
let yBottom = yAxis.getPixelForValue(0);
let yTop = yAxis.getPixelForValue(5);          
let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, yBottom, 0, yTop);
```

Please take a look at below sample and see how it works.

```js
const data = [2, 2.25, 3.3];

new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "bar",
  plugins: [{
    afterLayout: chart => {
      let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      let yAxis = chart.scales["y-axis-0"];
      let yBottom = yAxis.getPixelForValue(0);
      let yTop = yAxis.getPixelForValue(5);          
      let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, yBottom, 0, yTop);   
      gradient.addColorStop(0, '#FF5722');           
      gradient.addColorStop(0.5, '#FFC107'); 
      gradient.addColorStop(1, '#8BC34A');           
      chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = gradient;
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Evaluation",
      data: data
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: Math.min(...data) - 0.2,
          max: Math.max(...data) + 0.2,
          stepSize: 0.5
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I think this would help me. I just don't understand how and where I should put this extra code in the vue-chart. I do not use <canvas /> element but the Component <Bar /> that has the canvas inside. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it but I cannot find it in the documentation.

Comment: That is amazing @uminder, is it too much if I ask you also for a radius gradient? I don't really understand which numbers to put in a `createRadiusGradient`... Thanks

Comment: if you could be so kind, I created a dedicated question for it, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65127233/chartjs-radial-gradient-background-color-based-on-min-and-max-values

Comment: @Ayeye Brazo: I'm sorry but so far I've never used `createRadiusGradient`.