# Creating mixed Bar Chart with ReactJS using recharts or react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, recharts, react-chartjs-2

[image screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKvjA.png) I am trying to implement multiple Bar chart for the below requirement of chart in ReactJS using recharts or react-chartjs-2 library.
I was unable to find any direct solution available. Any suggestions how to create a similar type of chart

`const data = [ { type: "Sample 1", data: [600, 400, 200, 800] }, { type: "Sampel 2", data: [700, 300, 600, 600] }, { type: "Total", data: [1300, 700, 800, 1400] } ];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main requirement can be met by defining two `xAxes`, one for the individual values (`'x1'`), the other one for the total bar (`'x2'`).

> For further details, please consult the chapter ["Creating Multiple Axes"](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/?h=autoskip#creating-multiple-axes) from Chart.js documentation

Please take a look at below code sample and see how it works. While this is a pure `JavaScript` solution, the concept should also work for `react-chartjs-2`.

```js
const data = [{
  type: "Sample 1",
  data: [600, 400, 200, 800]
}, {
  type: "Sampel 2",
  data: [700, 300, 600, 600]
}, {
  type: "Total",
  data: [1300, 700, 800, 1400]
}];

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    datasets: [{
        label: data[0].type,
        xAxisID: 'x1',
        data: data[0].data,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        barPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: data[1].type,
        xAxisID: 'x1',
        data: data[1].data,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
        barPercentage: 1
      },
      {
        label: data[2].type,
        xAxisID: 'x2',
        data: data[2].data,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(172, 215, 250)',
        barPercentage: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        filter: item => item.text != 'Total'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 200
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
          id: 'x1'
        },
        {
          id: 'x2',
          display: false,
          offset: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks Uminder That worked prfectly
Can you please help me with adding the gadient only to the total bargraph

Comment: @Teja: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65120239/2358409. If you can't get it work, please post a new question for this new issue and me or somebody else will help you solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please take a look into the question that i have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618298/issue-with-chartjs-linear-gradient-for-the-mixed-bar-chart-in-reactjs-is-not-cal

Comment: @uminder Hello, I have a similar question except I need a bar and a line chart. I tried this solution but it did not work, is there anything else that needs to be done in the above to make it work with react-chartjs-2?